Can't find the title of this comedy about some people stuck in an area
I've seen this movie 10-15 years ago and my memories of it are blurry, but I will try to provide as many details as I remember. 
General details:

american comedy 
probably from the '80s or '90s 
it feels like "Beetlejuice" 
also, the music video of Travis - "Love will come through" reminds me a little bit of the movie (has a similar feeling)
action takes place in the '80s or '90s in an american small town

Plot and characters:

The movie is about a group of people (father, mother, daughter, daughter's lover, son, son's wife etc.) who can not leave the area around the house in which they live. They aren't stuck in the house. They are stuck in the area around the house. Whoever visits them and sleeps over night, gets stuck in the area. If they try to leave, something always happens so they can't leave. For instance, once they took the car, but it broke.
The main character is a young magician who falls in love with the daughter of the owner of the house.
Throughout the movie, the girl's father tries to catch / shoot a turkey (bird - maybe thanksgiving turkey, but I'm not sure) who lives in their house. The girl's father believed that if you kill the turkey, then you will be able, finally, to leave the house.

I know it sounds messed up, but it was a really cool movie. 
I would like to see it again.
Thanks for helping.

This is Dinner at Fred's (1997), starring Gil Bellows and Parker Posey...

Richard leaves his corporate office for a weekend at the country house
  of his fiancee, who is a daughter of his boss. On the way there he is
  forced to accept offer of lodging from local Fred and when he enters
  the house, the wacky family of Celia, her brother Dennis and their
  parents won't let him move on away from it. Family believes they are
  under the curse of the wild turkey, by which anyone who stays past
  midnight in the rural house is doomed to never leave.


Yes! This is the movie. Thank you so so much. I can't believe finally someone knew about it. Thank you again!
